# Only one of my fields submitting into mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Im trying to create a form where the user enters their name and a comment and it will be stored in my mySQL database and then printed below (like a basic comments board). 
My comment is successfully submitting my comments board and printing out below, but the name isn't.

this is my php coding:

```
$comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']);
 $name = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['name']); 
 if ($cokeboard != "") { 
 $query = "INSERT INTO cokeboard (name, comment) VALUES ('$comment', '$name')"; 
 mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
 $message = "Thanks for your comment!"; 
 }
//Print out existing comment 
$query = "SELECT * FROM cokeboard"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
$str_comments .= "<h3>" . $row['comment'] . "</h3>" . "<h6>" . $row['commDate'] . "</h6>" . "<h6>" . $row['name'] . "</h6>"; 
} 
 mysqli_free_result($result);
```

and here is the form that the user will submit in:

```
<form id="frmStudentFees" action="coke.php" method="post">
 Name:<input type='name' name='name'><br />
  <textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="comment"></textarea></br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form" /> 
</form>
```

and then to print the input out:

```
<?php
echo $str_comments;
?>
```

please bare in mind that I'm quite new to code.

many thanks

Comment: I'll keep my mental clothes on, thanks.

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO cokeboard (name, comment) VALUES ('$comment', '$name')";` Order of operations is key. You're inserting the comment into the name and the name into the comment. Also, you should have a look at prepared statements for MySQLI. You will also not need to use `clean_string` if you use `prepared` statments.

Comment: Also change your input type name to text.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']);
 $name_ = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['name']); 
 if ($cokeboard != "") { 
 $query = "INSERT INTO cokeboard (name, comment) VALUES ('$name_','$comment')"; 
 mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
 $message = "Thanks for your comment!"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is indeed valid [(as per W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html):

```
Name:<input type='name' name='name'><br />
                  ^^^^
```

However, many (including myself) like to use `text` as the element type for text-based form elements, depending on the type of browser used, and in this particular case, it could very well be the problem.

Therefore, use the following:

```
Name:<input type='text' name='name'><br />
```

**Yet this is the major issue;** you mixed up the order in `comment` and `name`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cokeboard (name, comment) VALUES ('$comment', '$name')";
                                                          ^^^^^^^     ^^^^
```

which should read as:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cokeboard (name, comment) VALUES ('$name', '$comment')";
```

or use backticks for your table and column names, which is a preferred method:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `cokeboard` (`name`, `comment`) VALUES ('$name', '$comment')";
```

the order of insertion is important.

Comment: I didn't see this detail. Fred is right. The type in input must be TEXT.

Comment: after insert, put a echo for verify if values is ok.

Comment: @phsaires please could you explain that? (i feel so dumb right now!!)

Comment: $comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']);
 $name_ = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['name']); 
//look here if the string is ok..........
echo $name_." ".$comment."<br />"; 
if ($cokeboard != "") { 
 $query = "INSERT INTO cokeboard (name, comment) VALUES ('$name_','$comment')"; 
 mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
 $message = "Thanks for your comment!"; 
 }

Comment: Your `clean_string()` function could be playing tricks on you. You should try using `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead, to test it. @user3169325 also check your column settings.

Comment: Plus, did you try `Name:<input type='text' name='name'><br />` @user3169325 using `type='text'` instead of `type='name'`?

Comment: And place/use `var_dump($_POST['name']);` just before your DB insert, it will show you what it's set to, or not. @user3169325 and remember, columns are case-sensitive. `name` is NOT the same as `Name` with a Capital `N`

Answer (score 0):

Try to `echo $query` and see what output you getting..